# Segmentation fault with vectors, but not sure what I did wrong

Tags: c++, vector

So when I run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
   int current_number = 0;
   vector<int>primes;
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
      current_number++;
      for(int h= 0; h < primes.size(); h++)
      {
         if(current_number % primes[h] == 0)
         {
            continue;
         }
         else
         {
            primes.push_back(current_number);
         }
      }
   }
   for(int x =0; x < 100; x++)
   {
      cout << primes[x];
   }
}
```

I get a segmentation fault. Im pretty sure it has something to do with vectorprimes. But, I'm not sure exactly what. The purpose of the code is to find every prime number between 1 and 100.

Comment: Did you bother to notice the inner for loop body never executes because `primes` is empty on inception and never changes?  E.g. `h < primes.size()` is false on inception and jettisons without ever entering the loop body. All this code ultimately does is increment a counter 100 times, then follows with a hard 100-iteration loop that dereferences cells in `primes` that don't exist. *Use a  debugger*. Single stepping in this code would have *quickly* showed you this.

Comment: When I do this: vector<int>primes = {2};, so that primes isn't empty on inception, the code does nothing. That's what I originally did, but I see your point.

Comment: Once you do that, it's still broken because each iteration where the modulo is non-zero will add to `primes`  (and thereby elongate the inner loop). You don't want to do that until *after* the inner loop is done, and knowing that it ran to completion without a zero-modulo test hit; not on every failed hit. And fyi, the last loop in the code should just be `for (auto x : primes) { std::cout << x << ' '; }`

Comment: Ah I see now, Thanks.

Comment: `for(int x =0; x < 100; x++)` is not prudent enough. I would prefer `for(unsigned x = 0; x < primes.size(); x++)` and then I would be sure I will not overrun `primes` inside the loop. Of course `for (auto value: primes)` would be even better here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the problems in the  posted code.

- The inner loop body will never be entered because `primes` is initially empty the only code that changes it is in that loop.
- Even after fixing the initial primes content with `{2}` and starting the counter loop with `3`, the logic in the inner loop is still wrong. It appends on ever non-zero modulo. That shouldn't be done *at all* in the inner loop. Rather, the loop should break on any zero-modulo, and the outer loop then only appends to `primes` when it knows the inner loop didn't break early.
- The final reporting loop assumes there are 100 primes in the first 100 numbers, which clearly isn't the case. Either it should be iterating based on container size, using iterators, or better still, just used ranged-for.
- Minor: the `current_number` is pointless; just use `i` from the outer loop and start it at `3`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> primes = {2};
    for (int i = 3; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        bool isprime = true;
        for (auto x : primes)
        {
            if (i % x == 0)
            {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isprime)
            primes.emplace_back(i);
    }

    for (auto x : primes)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

**Note**

There are better ways to do this. I suggest you investigate how to build a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or similar sieve. In truth, the above code is already over halfway there. It wouldn't take much more to do it.

Comment: This helped me to see the problem more thoroughly, thanks!